# Ice cross downhill competitions for amateurs?

Tags: ice-skating

I am looking for ice cross downhill competitions for amateurs.
I am not a professional ice skater, and not a professional hockey player.
But I like ice skating very much, and also I like to compete.
There are very interesting and inspirational competitions - [Red Bull Crashed Ice (Ice cross downhill)](https://www.redbull.com/us-en/tags/ice-cross-downhill).
[image]
Is there (in Europe) such a competitions just for amateurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://crashedice.redbull.com/en_FR/article/becoming-ice-cross-downhill-athlete) is a good reference for amateurs interested in this sport.

[Here](http://www.atsx.org/races) are the scheduled events. Although you missed this season completely it serves as a reference for possible future races. So yes, there are races in Europe.

The Riders Cup is particularly interesting for you, since that one is designed especially for athletes new to the sport. It's not exclusive to amateurs, since pros can as well participate, but it's as close as you can get to starting off with this sport.

> **Riders Cup**:
>
> The Riders Cup was created to make the sport of Ice Cross
>   Downhill more accessible to more athletes (male/female) worldwide. The
>   races are open to all comers and give athletes an introduction to the
>   sport under competitive conditions. The Riders Cup races are also open
>   to the top athletes of the sport as well, who can earn valuable world
>   championship points. The Riders Cup champion will be crowned at the
>   end of the season, and all official Riders Cup races count.